# Flutter replace all HTML Codes

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting json data from a wordpress website. Some of the content I fetch can have html codes like `&#8217 or &#8230` and I want to convert this to normal caracter like `'` or `...`

I can't seem to understand what function to use from the dart API to do this.

I've been able to convert them 1 by 1 using RegExp but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

```
new RegExp(r'&#8230;'),'...'))),
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a library called **html_unescape** that can do that, you can find it  [here](https://pub.dev/packages/html_unescape#-readme-tab-).

The steps to get it working are described there but as a quick reference:

1.- Include the dependency on your **pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  html_unescape: ^1.0.1+3
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

2.- Install the dependeny

Click on **Packagets get** while on the **pubsec.yaml** file

3.- Import it and use it:

```
import 'package:html_unescape/html_unescape.dart';

void main() {
  var unescape = HtmlUnescape();
  // prints ’ and …
  print(unescape.convert('&#8217; and &#8230;'));
}
```

**//EDIT**

Just as extra info, this is the google query I used to find this:

"convert html entities string flutter"